# How to get total default quantity stock in stock and salable quantity stock in product In Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, quantity

I want to get 2 values.
1. How much total quantity assigns to the product? example(50)
2. How much is the total quantity remaining for that particular product? 
Like if 50 quantity is there and if 5 quantity order so remaining or available quantity is 45.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have assigned source channels for the products? or only the default stock ?

Comment: default stock and salable stock, I need both.

Comment: Have you checked this blog https://webkul.com/blog/get-salable-quantity-in-magento-2-3/

Comment: @aravind it gives only one result. I need 2 data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a table inventory_reservation in this those ordered 5 quantity are stored, maybe this can help you

Answer (score 0):

To get salable Quantity

```
$sku = "ptoduct_sku";
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku');
$qty = $StockState->execute($sku);
print_r($qty);
```